# Mongodb query match with if condition form multiple fields with null values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a json where i am trying to **filter my pipeline with multiple fields where some fields can have null value as well**. sender.client and receiver.client may not always values

Below is the part of sample json:

```
{"sender" : {
        "id" : "5d95", 
        "name" : "Name1", 
        "phone" : "123456",
        "client" : "spec1"
    }, 
    "receiver" : {
        "id" : "5d95683", 
        "name" : "name2", 
        "phone" : "342235", 
        "client" : "spec1"
    }
}

{"sender" : {
        "id" : "52fes", 
        "name" : "Name2", 
        "phone" : "3334321",
        "client" : "spec2"
    }, 
    "receiver" : {
        "id" : "5efse", 
        "name" : "name3", 
        "phone" : "7353344", 
        "client" : "spec1"
    }
}
```

I am aiming to filter with condition if **(sender.client = spec1 or receiver.client =spec1)** then display all fields, i.e  if the name of the client matches then i have to display other required fields. I have been trying with $project and $match but match is not working with $cond , so i have taken alternate route with $eq but it's not helping me filter out my requirement. Below is my code:

```
    { 
        "$project" : {
            "sendername" : {
                "$cond" : {
                    "if" : {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$sender.client", 
                            "spec1"
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "then" : "$sender.name", 
                    "else" : 0.0
                }
            }, 
            "sendername1" : {
                "$cond" : {
                    "if" : {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$receiver.client", 
                            "spec1"
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "then" : "$receiver.name", 
                    "else" : 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to use $match inpace of $eq. How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$match` with `$expr`can filter based on the condition: `(sender.client = spec1 or receiver.client = spec1)`

> I am aiming to filter with condition if (sender.client = spec1 or
>   receiver.client = spec1) then display all fields, i.e if the name of
>   the client matches then i have to display other required fields.

You can add further filter to match the `name` field (there are two fields with "name",  `sender.name` and `receiver.name`; which one to match upon is not clear. I am assuming it can be any one).

```
var queryFilter = { $cond: {
                      if: { $or: [ 
                               { $eq: [ "$sender.client", "spec1" ] },
                               { $eq: [ "$receiver.client", "spec1" ] }
                            ]
                      },
                      then: true,
                      else: false
                 }
};

db.test.aggregate( [
{
    $match: { 
              $expr: { $eq: [ queryFilter,  true ],
              $or: [ { "sender.name" : "name3" }, { "receiver.name" : "name3" } ]  } 
    }
}
] )
```

The match filter is: `$expr: {...}`  *and*  `$or: [...]`.

Further, you can add other stages (e.g., `$project`) after the `$match` stage, as needed.